# Running cUrl cmd from Win7 doesn't work, but on Linux it does

Tags: utf-8, couchdb

Like the title says. I'm sending a simple cUrl cmd from Win7 to CouchDB on my Linux box, and it doesn't work. But if I run the same command in Linux, it works. I'm sending this:

```
curl -X POST 192.168.2.5:5984/test/testdoc -d '{"owner":{"fname":"test","lname":"ing"}}'
```

From windows, it keeps giving me a "error: bad request, reason:invalid UTF-8 JSON". 
I can run GET commands from windows just fine, I just can't seem to POST to CouchDB.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Windows shell (`cmd.exe`) uses quote marks differently from Mac OSX and Linux.

The simplest fix is to avoid single-quotes and use double quotes, with the double-quotes in the JSON document escaped:

```
curl -X PUT 192.168.2.5:5984/test/testdoc -d "{\"owner\":{\"fname\":\"test\",\"lname\":\"ing\"}}"
{"ok":true,"id":"testdoc","rev":"1-299729b3cb92a371136cb7331c66644d"}
```

Another option is to install a different shell such as Bash for Windows: http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/. Then you can follow documentation and do your own experiments more easily.