# Form object with @RequestPart parameter results in 404

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, curl, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am trying to create an URI where both a `MultipartFile` and a form object (bean) are required.

The method worked with the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void create(@RequestPart MultipartFile file,
                   @RequestPart String form) {
    // ...
}
```

And the following **curl** command:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost/files \
  -F file=@E:\path\to\file \
  -F form={"x":0,"y":0,"width":512,"height":512}
```

But as soon as I try to replace the string by a bean, I get a 404 response.

Modified code, not working, with a bean:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void create(@RequestPart MultipartFile file,
                   @RequestPart ClipForm form) {
    // ...
}
```

Adding the Content-Type header for each part in **curl** does not seem to help:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost/files \
  -F file=@E:\path\to\file;type=multipart/form-data \
  -F form={"x":0,"y":0,"width":512,"height":512};type=application/json
```

I am probably missing something that makes Spring think the request is not mapped to this method, but so far I cannot get what.

Comment: Shouldn't `type` be `Content-Type` in your curl string?

Comment: No, `type` is used to specify the Content-Type of parts in case of mutipart request. See [cURL manpage](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F).

Comment: in your request mapping you do not specify '/files' part - how it's supposed to be mapped?

Comment: also use -vv to view the actual content-type of the whole message(not the boundaries)

Comment: @BorisTreukhov the "/files" mapping is done by the encapsulating `@RestController`. Using `curl -v`, I see that I correctly get a global Content-Type to `multipart/form-data` with a correct boundary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, quoting everything in the **curl** command and using **bash** made this working.

```
curl -X 'POST' \
     -F 'file=@E:\path\to\file;type=multipart/form-data' \
     -F 'form={"x":0,"y":0,"width":512,"height":512};type=application/json' \
     'http://localhost/files'
```

I guess a character was misinterpreted by the Windows **cmd**.

---

**EDIT**

If you want it to get working in the Windows **cmd**, you will need to use [double quotes and escaped double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787000/7709086). It will not use the single quote like **bash**.

```
curl -X "POST" ^
     -F "file=@E:\path\to\file;type=multipart/form-data" ^
     -F "form={\"x\":0,\"y\":0,\"width\":512,\"height\":512};type=application/json" ^
     "http://localhost/files"
```